# Changing logging's 'basicConfig' which is already set

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am using the logging module in python as:

```
import logging, sys
logger= logging.getLogger(__file__)
logging.basicConfig(stream = sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s')
logger.debug("Hello World")
```

Now, after I have set the basic configuration on `line 3`, I want to have a command line argument that can change the output stream from sys.stderr to a file.

I have read the doc and it says that if both `filename` and `stream` are present at the same time, the `stream` is ignored.

Now, I wanna know how do change the stream to a file after I have already done the `basicConfig` thing in `line 3`?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you look in the Python sources for `logging/__init__.py`, you'll see that `basicConfig()` sets the handlers on the root logger object by calling `addHandler()`.  If you want to start from scratch, you could remove all existing handlers and then call `basicConfig()` again.

```
# Example to remove all root logger handlers and reconfigure. (UNTESTED)
import logging

# Remove all handlers associated with the root logger object.
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)

# Reconfigure logging again, this time with a file.
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'myfile.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s')
```

Comment: Also, use list comprehension remove all handlers here like the following code would be more simple :) `[logging.root.removeHandler(handler) for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]]`

Comment: @KevinGuan List comprehensions are for constructing lists.  When you want to run a statement in a loop, use a loop.

Comment: This was very helpful. I used this solution inside a function that set the logger with basicConfig. Now when I call this inside loops, I can log to different single logfiles in each iteration.

Comment: Since Python 3.8, `basicConfig` now accept a [``force``](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.basicConfig) argument to remove existing root handlers.

Comment: @Spack, are you saying that we can remove lines 5+6 above and set line 9 to something like `logging.basicConfig(filename='myfile.log', ..., force = True)` ?

Answer (score 18):

> Attribution to be given in [Spack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047097/spack), for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158048/changing-loggings-basicconfig-which-is-already-set#comment106878272_12158233). I am just expanding the idea in a proper answer

In 2022 and using Python 3.8, we can use the `force` input of `basicConfig` method

As per Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.basicConfig)

> **force**
>
> If this keyword argument is specified as true, any existing handlers
> attached to the root logger are removed and closed, before carrying
> out the configuration as specified by the other arguments.

Based on OP code sample, can just add the following line

```
logging.basicConfig(filename = 'my_file.log', level = logging.DEBUG, format = '%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s', force = True)
```