# Python logging - check location of log files?

Tags: python, linux, file, logging, python-logging

What is the methodology for knowing where Python log statements are stored?

i.e. if i do:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Test')
```

Where could I find the logfile? Also, when I call:

```
logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Is that somehow related to how the logger will behave/save?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `logging` module uses handlers attached to loggers to decide how, where, or even if messages ultimately get stored or displayed.  You can configure `logging` by default to write to a file as well.  You should really read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), but if you call `logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name)` where `log_file_name` is the name of the file you want messages written to (note that you have to do this before anything else in `logging` is called at all), then all messages logged to all loggers (unless some further reconfiguration happens later) will be written there.  Be aware of what level the logger is set to though; if memory serves, `info` is below the default log level, so you'd have to include `level=logging.INFO` in the arguments to `basicConfig` as well for your message to end up in the file.

As to the other part of your question, `logging.getLogger(some_string)` returns a `Logger` object, inserted in to the correct position in the hierarchy from the root logger, with the name being the value of `some_string`.  Called with no arguments, it returns the root logger.  `__name__` returns the name of the current module, so `logging.getLogger(__name__)` returns a `Logger` object with the name set to the name of the current module.  This is a common pattern used with `logging`, as it causes the logger structure to mirror your code's module structure, which often makes logging messages much more useful when debugging.

Comment: how do you reconfigure the logger after some logs have been written already?

Comment: Per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158048/changing-loggings-basicconfig-which-is-already-set), basicConfig sets the handler on the root logger object (or the logger object configured with your given module `example_logger = logging.getLogger('example')`). Thus, you could remove the existing handler and call basic config again. Alternatively, you could create a different logger object `example2_logger = logging.getLogger('example')` and set different configs on this object.

Answer (score 24):

To get the log location of a simple file logger, try

```
logging.getLoggerClass().root.handlers[0].baseFilename
```

Comment: It throws exception to me

Comment: What's the exception? You could try using a debugger and poking around those objects until you find what you need

Comment: This assumes that the logger had a FileHandler, which is not always the case. Better make sure that the handlers contain a FileHandler object.

Comment: It throws an exception to me as well: "AttributeError: 'StreamHandler' object has no attribute 'baseFilename'"

Comment: In my case it is working logging.handlers[0].baseFilename

Answer (score 5):

Some good answers on this, but top answer didn't work for me because I was using a different type of file handler, and the handler.stream doesn't provide the path, but file handle, and getting the path out of that is somewhat non-obvious. Here's my solution:

```
import logging
from logging import FileHandler

# note, this will create a new logger if the name doesn't exist, 
# which will have no handlers attached (yet)
logger = logging.getLogger('<name>')

for h in logger.handlers:
    # check the handler is a file handler 
    # (rotating handler etc. inherit from this, so it will still work)
    # stream handlers write to stderr, so their filename is not useful to us
    if isinstance(h, FileHandler):
        # h.stream should be an open file handle, it's name is the path
        print(h.stream.name)
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot impart name 'FileHandler' from 'logging.handlers'

Comment: @CodePrinz, good catch, the base class lives in the logging module, not the handlers module. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

To find the logfile location, try instantiating your `log` object in a Python shell in your environment and looking at the value of:

`log.handlers[0].stream`

Comment: I get an IndexError, since my object has no handlers.

Comment: Or an AttributeErrror:'_LiveLoggingNullHandler' object has no attribute 'stream'

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question @zallarak. Unfortunately, while they're easy to create, `Loggers` are difficult to inspect. This gets the filenames of all `Handlers` for a `logger`:

```
filenames = []
for handler in logger.handlers:
    try:
        filenames.append(handler.fh.name)
    except:
        pass
```

The `try` block handles exceptions that occur when the filename lookup fails.