# Logging decorator with basicConfig settings as arguments

Tags: python, logging, decorator

**EDIT :** I restructured the question and added headings in the hope it will be easier to read

## The Problem

I'm trying to add some functionality to the logging decorator in the [python decorator library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Logging_decorator_with_specified_logger_.28or_default.29).

One of the options I wanted to add is being able to set the logging level by providing a dictionary as input. However, no matter what level I set it always returns the same results.

---

## The failing test

After running the setup code below, I'm testing it by running the following:

```
@log_with(setConfig={'level':logging.INFO})
def c(msg):
    print(msg)

c('OMG!!')
```

which returns:

```
INFO:__main__:Running c


DEBUG:__main__:The following arguments have been received:# <-- This should not be here
('OMG!!',)

The following keyword arguments have been received:
{}


INFO:__main__:Returning c
OMG!!
```

I'm using WinPython 2.7.6 in a portable, non-registered way if this matters. The test fails in the qtconsole

---

## The set up code

```
import functools, logging


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class log_with(object):
    '''Logging decorator that allows you to log with a
specific logger or set one up on the go.
'''

    def __init__(self,logger=None,funcentry='Running {}',funcexit='Returning {}',setConfig=None):

        self.logger        = logger
        self.ENTRY_MESSAGE = funcentry
        self.EXIT_MESSAGE  = funcexit
        self.setConfig     = setConfig


    def __call__(self, func):
        '''Returns a wrapper that wraps func.
The wrapper will log the entry and exit points of the function
with specified level.
'''
        # set logger if it was not set earlier
        if not self.logger:
            self.logger = logging.getLogger(func.__module__)
            logging.basicConfig(**self.setConfig)

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
            self.logger.info(self.ENTRY_MESSAGE.format(func.__name__)+'\n\n')
            self.logger.debug("The following arguments have been received:\n{}\n\nThe following keyword arguments have been received:\n{}\n\n".format(args,kwds))
            try:
                f_result = func(*args, **kwds)
                self.logger.info(self.EXIT_MESSAGE.format(func.__name__))
                return f_result
            except Exception:
                self.logger.exception("An exception was raised:\n\n")
        return wrapper
```

---

## Ideas I had and things I tried

### Resetting all handlers

I tried to amend the `if not self.logger` loop in the decorator by removing all handlers that might exist, i.e.

```
....
if not self.logger:
    for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
        logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
....
```

based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158233/2488942) however this didn't work either, i.e. the output stayed the same.

### I don't understand decorators and/or the logging module!

I removed

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

and ran the code again. This time no logging message was printed to screen at all. To me this means that there is something wrong with the `if not self.logger` loop in the `__call__` method, i.e. the logger is not created.

I have no idea why though.....

Comment: It seems that the logger in the `__call__` function is not properly created... when I remove the initial `log=logging.getLogger(..)` the decorator doesn't work, i.e. no logging calls are printed at all... ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I learned:

1. It looks like using `basicConfig()` sets some global variables for logging. Changing the logging level seems to change it globally rather than just for this call.
2. Whether implementing a decorator as a class or as a function seems to make a difference. While not totally sure, I believe that by implementing my `self.setConfig` in `__init__`, I changed the class for all functions I decorated. I deduct this from the solution I found, which is implementing the decorator as a function:

This it what seems to work (even though I'm a little puzzled about the order in which things are returned):

```
def log_with_func(funcentry='Running {}',funcexit='Returning {}',setConfig=None):
    ENTRY_MESSAGE = funcentry
    EXIT_MESSAGE  = funcexit
    def func(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
            for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
                logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            if setConfig:
                logging.basicConfig(**setConfig)
            else:
                logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
            logger.info(ENTRY_MESSAGE.format(f.__name__)+'\n\n')
            logger.debug("The following arguments have been received:\n{}\n\nThe following keyword arguments have been received:\n{}\n\n".format(args,kwds))
            try:
                f_result = f(*args, **kwds)
                logger.info(EXIT_MESSAGE.format(f.__name__))
                return f_result
            except Exception:
                logger.exception("An exception was raised:\n\n")
        return wrapper
    return func
```

Applied it looks like this:

```
In [24]: @log_with_func()
    ...: def aa(msg):
    ...:     print(msg + 'from a')
    ...:     

In [25]: @log_with_func(setConfig={'level':logging.DEBUG})
    ...: def bb(msg):
    ...:     print(msg + 'from b')
    ...:     

In [26]: print(aa('OMG!!!'))
    ...: print(bb('OMG!!!'))
    ...: print(aa('OMG!!!'))
    ...: 
INFO:__main__:Running aa


INFO:__main__:Returning aa
INFO:__main__:Running bb


DEBUG:__main__:The following arguments have been received:
('OMG!!!',)

The following keyword arguments have been received:
{}


INFO:__main__:Returning bb
INFO:__main__:Running aa


INFO:__main__:Returning aa
OMG!!!from a
None
OMG!!!from b
None
OMG!!!from a
None

In [27]:
```