# Python - logging for each archive

Tags: python, logging

I need create a file .log to every py archive.

Example of tree I need:

- /FILES/File_1.py
- /FILES/File_2.py
- /LOGS/File_1.log
- /LOGS/File_2.log
- /LOGS/Main.log
- /log_config.py
- /main.py

There may be an additional file with the 'logging' configuration, as in the main it will be the call for each of the scripts in the 'FILES' folder.

Now in the application, what I tried:

In log_config.py:

```
import logging

def write_log(name):

     FORMAT = "%(asctime)s :: lvl: %(levelname)s :: line: %(lineno)d :: funcName: %(funcName)s :: message: %(message)s"
     logging.basicConfig(
     format=FORMAT,
     level=logging.DEBUG,
     filemode='w',
     filename="LOG/"+name+".log"
)
```

In main.py:

```
from log_config import write_log, logging
from FILES.File_1 import save_File_1
from FILES.File_2 import save_File_2

write_log("Main")
logging.info('Test Main')

save_File_1()
save_File_2()
```

In File_1.py:

```
from log_config import write_log, logging

def save_File_1():
     write_log("File 1")

     logging.info("test File_1")
```

In File_2.py:

```
from log_config import write_log, logging

def save_File_2():
     write_log("File 2")

     logging.info("test File_2")
```

Result:
Only 1 .log file is created, named "Main.log", and has recorded in it:

```
2023-04-19 11:09:33,544 :: lvl: INFO :: line: 6 :: funcName: <module> :: message: Test Main
2023-04-19 11:09:33,544 :: lvl: INFO :: line: 6 :: funcName: save_File_1 :: message: test File_1
2023-04-19 11:09:33,544 :: lvl: INFO :: line: 6 :: funcName: save_File_2 :: message: test File_2
```

If someone can give me a light for this resolution, I would be enormously grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution.
I found the answer here: [Python logging - new log file each loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591352/python-logging-new-log-file-each-loop-iteration)

In log_config.py:

```
import logging
import sys

def write_log(logger_name, level=logging.DEBUG):
     logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
     logger.setLevel(level)
     format_string = ("%(asctime)s :: %(name)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(funcName)s:"
                 "%(lineno)d :: %(message)s")
     log_format = logging.Formatter(format_string)

     # Creating and adding the console handler
     console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
     console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
     logger.addHandler(console_handler)
     # Creating and adding the file handler
     file_handler = logging.FileHandler("LOG/"+logger_name+".log", mode='a')
     file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
     logger.addHandler(file_handler)
     return logger
```

In main.py:

```
from log import write_log
from FILES.File_1 import save_File_1
from FILES.File_2 import save_File_2

logger = write_log("Main")
logger.debug('Test Main')

save_File_1()
save_File_2()
```

In File_1.py:

```
from log import write_log
import logging

def save_File_1():
    logger = write_log("File 1")
    logger.debug('Test File 1')
```