# Logging is appending current day info on previous day log file python

Tags: python, logging

I am using logging module and after 12 am midnight of local system logging is appending on same old file i.e 26th Dec logs are appending in 25122021.log.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import logging
from config import *
import time
from datetime import datetime
import datetime


def readCSV():
    try:
        logfile=LogDirectory+"\\"+str(datetime.datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")).replace("/", "")+".log"
        logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='a',level=logging.INFO)
        logging.info("Python CollateralValidation Satrted")
        start_time = time.time()                  
        dfFileNames=Utility.GetFileNames(filecount)
        try:
            if len(dfFileNames) > 0:
                logging.info("CollateralValidation-> file count "+str(len(dfFileNames)))
                abc=CollateralValidation(dfFileNames)
            else:
                logging.info("CollateralValidation-> THREAD SLEEP NO FILES")
                time.sleep(DelayTime)
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        except:
            logging.exception("CollateralValidation Exception->readCSV->")
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("CollateralValidation Exception")

while True:
readCSV()
time.sleep(DelayTime)
```

result:

```
2021-12-26 12:19:45,821 CollateralValidation:Utility-> GetFileNames : |SELECT CFU_BATCH_DATE,CFU_FILE_NAME,CFU_TMID,CFU_CREATED_DT,CFU_SUCESS_COUNT,CFU_FAIL_COUNT,CFU_CREATED_BY,CFU_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS,CFU_ID,CFU_DTL_PARENTID,CFU_NO_SPLIT_FILES FROM(SELECT TO_CHAR(CFU_BATCH_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') CFU_BATCH_DATE,CFU_FILE_NAME,CFU_TMID,TO_CHAR(CFU_CREATED_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') CFU_CREATED_DT,CFU_SUCESS_COUNT,CFU_FAIL_COUNT,CFU_CREATED_BY,CFU_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS,CFU_ID,CFU_DTL_PARENTID,CFU_NO_SPLIT_FILES FROM NCSUSR.COLLATERAL_FILE_UPLOAD WHERE CFU_FILE_STATUS='P' ORDER BY CFU_CREATED_DT ASC) WHERE ROWNUM < 6
2021-12-26 12:19:45,821 CollateralValidation-> THREAD SLEEP NO FILES
2021-12-26 12:23:45,834 Python CollateralValidation Satrted
2021-12-26 12:23:45,834 CollateralValidation:Utility-> GetFileNames : |SELECT CFU_BATCH_DATE,CFU_FILE_NAME,CFU_TMID,CFU_CREATED_DT,CFU_SUCESS_COUNT,CFU_FAIL_COUNT,CFU_CREATED_BY,CFU_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS,CFU_ID,CFU_DTL_PARENTID,CFU_NO_SPLIT_FILES FROM(SELECT TO_CHAR(CFU_BATCH_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') CFU_BATCH_DATE,CFU_FILE_NAME,CFU_TMID,TO_CHAR(CFU_CREATED_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') CFU_CREATED_DT,CFU_SUCESS_COUNT,CFU_FAIL_COUNT,CFU_CREATED_BY,CFU_NO_OF_ATTEMPTS,CFU_ID,CFU_DTL_PARENTID,CFU_NO_SPLIT_FILES FROM NCSUSR.COLLATERAL_FILE_UPLOAD WHERE CFU_FILE_STATUS='P' ORDER BY CFU_CREATED_DT ASC) WHERE ROWNUM < 6
2021-12-26 12:23:45,834 CollateralValidation-> THREAD SLEEP NO FILES
```

The shown result is of **25122021.log** .I am not understanding as to why it doesn't create new file when it is next day.

Comment: print `datetime.datetime.now()` to see python time. Run `date` command in linux terminal. compare the two with your local time.

Comment: Obviously the time used for logfile rollover is different from the time you log as part of the message. Server with different time zone settings? Differently set clocks? - nothing we could solve I fear, check your hardware settings.

Comment: @sumant Agnihotri datetime.datetime.now() gives current date as well .my logfile variable gets the proper str of current date name i.e 26122021 but log get appended in previous day file.is there any way to kill logging module and run it again when function gets called so that next day can be picked up ?

Comment: oh is the `def readCSV():` function only called once, and not reinitiated for every log. in that case your `logfile` variable is only set once.

Comment: @Suman Agnihotri def readCSV() gets called after every 2 mins .I have updated my question code for better reference .

Comment: You can try to reset the root logger, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158048/changing-loggings-basicconfig-which-is-already-set